# How to generate dictionary from two lists, keys with multiple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a series of jpgs that are photos of sites. For some sites I have more than one photo. I have unique IDs for each site. Each photo has a name like 'IDPhoto1', 'IDPhoto2', etc. I would like to isolate the unique IDs in one list and the full paths of the file in another, then generate a dictionary from the two lists where the unique ID is the key and the full paths containing the same ID in the file name would be the values. I can generate the lists, but am unsure how to create the dictionay.

I'm updating this to include the code I have so far, which is not much. I tried someone's suggesting below to create the dictionary, but I'm not getting the right values associated with the right keys, as well as the fact that there should be multiple values for some keys. How can I generate a dictionary that matches values and keys with the same ID?

UPDATE: I think I am getting closer I've edited the code below. Now I am getting the right keys associated with the right values, but am having associated multiple values with each key:

```
import os, PyPDF2, re
pgs_dir = r'P:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics'
jpg_paths = []
jpg_ID = []
pattern = re.compile(r'Photo.*')

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(jpgs_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullPath = dirpath+'\\'+filename
        if re.search(pattern,filename):
            jpg_paths.append(fullPath)
            file_ID = re.sub(pattern,'',filename)
            jpg_ID.append(file_ID)
            jpg_ID_unique = set(jpg_ID)

for j in jpg_ID:
for jp in jpg_paths:
    if j in jp:
        if j not in pdf_dict.keys():
            pdf_dict[j] = jp
        else:
            pdf_dict.update({j:jp})

print pdf_dict
```

FINAL EDIT:

To better focus this question I've edited the original post to more clearly ask one question. I also was able to generate some code that worked for me, it is posted below:

```
import os, re
jpgs_dir = r'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\jpgs_reduced'
jpg_paths = []
jpg_ID = []
pattern = re.compile(r'Photo.*')
pdf_dict = {}
pdf_file_path = r'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\TIFS'
```

convert_txt_file = r'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\Convert_JPGS_Batch.txt'

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(jpgs_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullPath = dirpath+'\\'+filename
        if re.search(pattern,filename):
            jpg_paths.append(fullPath)
            file_ID = re.sub(pattern,'',filename)
            jpg_ID.append(file_ID)
            jpg_ID_unique = set(jpg_ID)

print 'total number of unique IDs =',len(jpg_ID_unique)

for j in jpg_ID_unique:
    for jp in jpg_paths:
        if j in jp:
            pdf_dict.setdefault(j, []).append(jp)
print pdf_dict
```

Also here is example of one of the resulting dictionary key and values:

{'35101023189S1': ['D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\jpgs_reduced\35101023189S1Photo1.jpg', 'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\jpgs_reduced\35101023189S1Photo2.jpg', 'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\jpgs_reduced\35101023189S1Photo3.jpg', 'D:\Records\GIS\Projects\D04_OHS\OverheadSignStructurePics\jpgs_reduced\35101023189S1Photo4.jpg']

Comment: How do you imagine the dictionary could be created?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I can compare list elements to find the corresponding filepaths in one list that contain the unique IDs contained in the other, but then am unsure of what to do from there.

Comment: Did you try to make the dictionary at the same time you create the list of file paths?

Comment: What do the lists that you have generated look like? Please post any code and sample data that you have.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a question about basic data structures in Python (`list` and `dict`) or a question about how to use a library to  generate PDFs from images. You should simplify or break down the question to its essential basics. If it's the former, then give an actual example of the kind of data structure which you think should be **output** by a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list_of_unique_ids = ['IDPhoto1', 'IDPhoto2', 'IDPhoto3']
>>> list_of_corresponding_paths = [r'Path/To/Photo1', r'Path/To/Photo2', r'Path/To/Photo3']
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(list_of_unique_ids, list_of_corresponding_paths))
>>> print dictionary
{'IDPhoto3': 'Path/To/Photo3', 'IDPhoto2': 'Path/To/Photo2', 'IDPhoto1': 'Path/To/Photo1'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try this I was unsure of whether or not the IDs would be associated with the right file paths as the lists aren't ordered..  I get confused with dictionaries

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work, the keys are not associated with the right values, and some keys should have multiple values

Comment: The lists needs to be in the same order for this to work i.e. element at index 0 of `list_of_unique_ids` should correspond to element at index 0 of `list_of_corresponding_paths`, otherwise you've lost information by splitting into two lists